# Can't cycle elements in array into buttons using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
myButtons = [
    "E", "CE", "C", "/", "%",
    "7", "8", "9", "*", "x²",
    "4", "5", "6", "-", "√",
    "1", "2", "3", "+", "^",
    "0", ".", "+/-", "!", "="
]

for i in myButtons:
    for j in range(0,4):
        for k in range(0,4):
            tkinter.Button(window, text=i,bg="blue", width=10, height=3, command=echo(i)).grid(row=j, column=k)
```

Can't cycle array elements into buttons, i expected buttons with value from array, but got last element as value of many buttons. Why it is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest such a code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


def echo(text):
    tk.messagebox.showinfo('info', text)

root = tk.Tk()
myButtons = [
    "E", "CE", "C", "/", "%",
    "7", "8", "9", "*", "x²",
    "4", "5", "6", "-", "√",
    "1", "2", "3", "+", "^",
    "0", ".", "+/-", "!", "="
]

for i, text in enumerate(myButtons):
    tk.Button(root, text=text, bg="blue",
              width=10, height=3,
              command=lambda t=text: echo(t)).grid(row=i//5, column=i % 5)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Imperions your code doesn't work properly because you are going to create 16 buttons for every myButtons element. I. e. 16 buttons for "E", 16 for "CE" and so on.

Comment: @Imperions also `echo(i)` is a mistake probably. You should put a function there, without `()`. If you need to pass arguments in, then you can use a lambda this way: `command=lambda i: echo(i)`

Comment: Thank you, sooo much!) I appreciate your help

Comment: it returns error: TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'i'

Comment: @Imperions oh, sorry, my bad. I fixed it and updated my answer.

Comment: @Imperions a function passed to `command` parameter would take no arguments when the click event occurs. So we use a named argument (`t=text`) in order to 'transport' the `text` variable into the lambda. The lambda works as a delegate to `echo` function. It's a common trick to pass arguments to event handlers.

Comment: @Imperions i // 5 means the amount of 5's (rows). I. e. 0 // 5 == 0 - 0th row, 7 // 5 == 1 - there is 1 5's in 7 (1th row), 10 // 5 == 2 - it means there are 2 5's in 10 (2th row). `//` is the floor division, because we don't need a float result. i % 5 gives us a column number because a column number can be considered as a remainder from i // 5 division. I. e. 0 % 5 == 0(th column), 1 % 5 == 1(th column), 7 % 5 == 2(th column). 7 % 5 is 2 because 2 is remained after division. I. e. we have 1 5's and 2 is a remainder. Another example: 23 % 5 - we have 4 5's (4 rows) and 3 (cols) as a remainder.

Comment: @Imperions I hope you would catch the idea and my English is understandable.

Comment: I got it. Your English is pretty good.(But we are saying 1st and 2nd, 3rd, not 1th and 2th. Starting from 4 it would be 4th). Thank you again

Comment: @Imperions Oh, I had heard about st, nd, rd, but it went out of my mind. You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

I think you wanted to do this

```
myButtons = [
    ["E", "CE", "C", "/", "%"],
    ["7", "8", "9", "*", "x²"],
    ["4", "5", "6", "-", "√"],
    ["1", "2", "3", "+", "^"],
    ["0", ".", "+/-", "!", "="]
]

for j, row in enumerate(myButtons):
    for k, i in enumerate(row):
            tkinter.Button(window, text=i,bg="blue", width=10, height=3, command=echo(i)).grid(row=j, column=k)
```

Note, I have changed myButtons to a list of lists as I am assuming this is a static list. If you want to use original list, we can refactor the solution by getting the quotient and remainder on division by 5 as j and k respectively